# How to dynamically configure the runtime for Nextjs API routes

Tags: javascript, next.js, cloudflare, edge-runtime

I have deployed my Next.js 13 app on Cloudflare Pages. Since it has a few API routes, I had to export the runtime variable from each route as follows.

```js
export const runtime = "edge"
```

However, when I do local development, I need to change this to 'nodejs'. Therefore I tried supplying this value through a Next.js environment variable, but it's not working on Cloudflare.

Does anyone know an easier way to toggle between these two runtimes for prod and dev? Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think we can archive your issue by use the .env file to config the variables in production or development. With `.env` for production and `.env.local` for development.

Updated:
Go to the file `next.config.js` and add a config:

```js
const nextConfig = {
...
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    runtime: process.env.RUNTIME
  }
...
}
```

Now we can use this config with `next/config` package. Eg.

```js
// /app/pages.tsx

import getConfig from 'next/config';

...
const {serverRuntimeConfig} = getConfig();

console.log(serverRuntimeConfig.runtime); => the value depends on .env or .env.locale file.
```

It works for me.

Comment: I already tried with .env files, but it didn't work. .env variables are loaded after determining the runtime I guess.

Comment: I was updated the comment. Could you please try again?

Comment: `serverRuntimeConfig` is marked as deprecated, isn't it :/